# R, Colors in GGally::ggsurv

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot multiple survival curves together.
I'm using :

```
library('GGally')
all_data <- rbind((cbind(data_0, type = 'cs0')),(cbind(data_1, type = 'cs1')),(cbind(data_2, type = 'cs2')))
ggsurv(sf.varmints, CI=TRUE)
```

I get this plot [image: survival curve]

But I want the confidence intervals to have the same color as its line. Now all of them are black, I want them to be red, green, blue. Also color of points that mark censored observations to have the same color as their lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.